# Packet tracer 7.1 won't lauch Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, cisco

I am trying to run PacketTracer 7.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, everything installs fine, everything is accepted, however when I run the `packettracer` command, nothing happens... the shell just stays there.

I've already tried several solutions (adding lines and paths to the launch scripts, chmod on bash files, reinstalling, modifying paths), but nothing is happening, I did a clean installation on 2 different machines.

I finally was able to get some error messages out of it by running `strace -f -o ~/Documents cpt_trace` ran `grep` and got the following output.

```
$cat cpt_trace | grep error

3064  writev(2, [{"./PacketTracer7", 15}, {": ", 2}, {"error while loading shared libra"..., 36}, {": ", 2}, {"libicui18n.so.52", 16}, {": ", 2}, {"cannot open shared object file", 30}, {": ", 2}, {"No such file or directory", 25}, {"\n", 1}], 10) = 131

$ cat cpt_trace | grep such
3063  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3063  access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3063  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3063  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3063  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib/tls/x86_64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)<br>
3064  stat("/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff431ef330) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib/tls/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib/tls", 0x7fff431ef330) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib/x86_64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff431ef330) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib", 0x7fff431ef330) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/tls/x86_64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/opt/pt/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff431ef330) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/tls/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/opt/pt/lib/tls", 0x7fff431ef330) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/x86_64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/opt/pt/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff431ef330) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/libpng12.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/libX11.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/libxslt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/libxml2.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/opt/pt/lib/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff431eea30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7fff431eea30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7fff431eea30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff431eea30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7fff431eea30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7fff431eea30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/lib/tls/x86_64/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff431eea30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/lib/tls/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/lib/tls", 0x7fff431eea30)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/lib/x86_64/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff431eea30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/lib/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff431eea30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/usr/lib/tls/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7fff431eea30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/usr/lib/x86_64/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff431eea30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  open("/usr/lib/libicui18n.so.52", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3064  writev(2, [{"./PacketTracer7", 15}, {": ", 2}, {"error while loading shared libra"..., 36}, {": ", 2}, {"libicui18n.so.52", 16}, {": ", 2}, {"cannot open shared object file", 30}, {": ", 2}, {"No such file or directory", 25}, {"\n", 1}], 10) = 131
```

Comment: Resolved, modified tpl.linguist and tpl.packettracer.
The line PTDIR=III, I changed it to PTDIR=/opt/pt.
Still did not work. Had to run it from /opt/pt/bin ./PacketTracer7

Answer (score 2):

Resolved.
I modified the `tpl.linguist` and `tpl.packettracer`.

On the line with `PTDIR=III`, I changed it to `PTDIR=/opt/pt`.

Still did not work. Had to run it from `/opt/pt/bin ./PacketTracer7`, and it works now.

Comment: You can add `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/pt/bin/"` to your `.bashrc` file (located in your home), after a restart of the shell you should be able to run it everywhere simply using `PacketTracer7`