# Cisco Packet Tracer 7.1 won't start

Tags: cisco

I installed Packet Tracer 7.1 using command lines. It installed fine but when I type `packettracer` it just says

```
starting packettracer 7.1
```

but doesn't work. I tried every solution I found on the internet but they didn't work.

Comment: What commands did you use to install?

Comment: I opened terminal in the folder and typed "./install" it installed , it even said " installation successful ..

Comment: I don't claim to be an expert on packettracer, and I'm not one, but it sounds like you might want to try installing from somewhere else. Is it available in the apt repositories? You could try uninstalling your current installation and installing through apt.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to run Cisco Packet Tracer 7.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 by doing the following:

1-Cisco Packet Tracer 7.1 requires an older version of a package not present on Ubuntu 16.04 so you need to get it by typing

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.7_amd64.deb
```

2- To install the package you just downloaded type

```
sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.7_amd64.deb
```

3- Verify proper installation using this commands

```
sudo updatedb; locate libicui18n
```

Check for the following packages to be installed:

- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52.1

Those are the packages needed by Cisco Packet Tracer to work properly.

Now you can type `packettracer` on terminal and the program should start.

Comment: I think this could be the answer for this  question as well https://askubuntu.com/questions/944717/packet-tracer-7-1-wont-lauch-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: Getting a 404 not found error in step 1

Comment: get it from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libicu52/52.1-3ubuntu0.7

Answer (score 5):

Navigate to the directory where `PacketTracer` is installed (this is the default):

```
cd /opt/pt/bin
```

then run `PacketTracer7`

```
./PacketTracer7
```

Now, if it shows a list of "libqt5xxx" missing libraries, please install them all.

```
sudo apt install libqt5xxx*
```

Remember, just write everything that is behind the first "."(dot) and to put the * in the end of the name of the package.

In my case, it was a package named "libQt5Script.so.5", so I did this:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5script*
```

After that, running PacketTracer7

```
./PacketTracer7
```

should now work.

Comment: I modified the `tpl.linguist` and `tpl.packettracer`. On the line with `PTDIR=III`, I changed it to `PTDIR=/opt/pt`. And after that I did what this answer says. Thank you

Comment: Using your method, I figured out that I have to install `libqt5webkit5`, `libqt5xml5` and `libqt5script*` to make Packet Tracer 7.1.1 run on Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the libraries required by using this command:

```
cd /opt/pt/bin
ldd Packettracer7
```

you'll see all the libraries inclunding the missing ones 
So to solve this problem just copy the library missing like :

```
sudo cp /opt/pt/lib/libname /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

And ta da!!!
**Problem solved**

Comment: Very helpful. In my case libpng12 was missing and I downloaded it here and just installed it: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download

Answer (score 1):

i fixed this by

`wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-8+deb8u6_amd64.deb`

then this command line

`sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-8+deb8u6_amd64.deb`

and finally

`packettracer`

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue between packet tracer 7.1 and Ubuntu 16.04 which blocks packet tracer from starting. Packet tracer needs a library libicui18n.so.52 which has been updated with libicui18n.so.55 in Ubuntu 16.04. To solve this issue, we have to download and install the older version of this library. Older version of this library is available in a Debian package at :-

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.7_amd64.deb.

Run following commands to download and install this package

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg –i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.7_amd64.deb
sudo updatedb
```

Once package is installed, run following command to update the library path

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pt/lib /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7
```

Source :- https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/ccna-online-training/download-packet-tracer-for-windows-and-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal type packettracer, make sure you use two t's, packettracer not packetracer, not case sensitive, do not need to change directory, I am running version 7.1.1 on ubuntu 14.04, no need to type packettracer7 or packettracer7.1.1 just packettracer.

My Packettracer program in /opt/pt where it is installed is named packettracer.